# Change file encoding with PHP

Tags: php, encoding

I tried lots of methods, but none of them worked.

```
$file = "/home/ozgurj2l/public_html/turk/kültürel değişim.txt";
$d = fopen($file, "r");
$data = fread($d, 4000);
echo $data;
```

Result:

```
$bjbj�s�s.(��b �������||||�\
```

How can I do it?

Comment: what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow new user. You should accept the answer you think its the answer of your question. And please take a 2 minute [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to use Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
mb_convert_encoding($data,"UTF-8");
```